# Как вытащить подстроку из строки?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть строка:

```
text = "Пельмени 'шашлык' деньги"
```

Как из этой строки вытащить слово шашлык и поместить её в отдельную переменную?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте модуль `re`. Разбирайтесь в регулярках.

Comment: @NNL993, Спассибо

Comment: Откуда известно, что нужно вытащить слово шашлык?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - можно разделить текст по словам

```py
text = "Пельмени 'шашлык' деньги"
word = text.split()[1]  # Разделение строки на слова и обращение по индексу
print(word)
```

Вывод:

```
'шашлык'
```